# How to execute a multi-line curl command in github pages on push?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

This is my workflow so far, github tells me that there's and error on line 8, but I can't find it.

```
name: restartServer
on: [push]
jobs:
  check-bats-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: >
        curl --location --request POST 'https://panel.discordbothosting.com/api/client/servers/fd21d417/power' \
          --header 'Accept: application/json' \
          --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
          --header 'Authorization: Bearer APIKEY' \
          --data-raw '{
            "signal": "restart"
          }'
```

Answer (score 6):

Replace:

```
- run: >
```

With:

```
- run: |
```

And indent your script 2 more spaces:

```
name: restartServer
on: [push]
jobs:
 check-bats-version:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
     - run: |
         curl --location --request POST 'https://panel.discordbothosting.com/api/client/servers/fd21d417/power' \
           --header 'Accept: application/json' \
           --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
           --header 'Authorization: Bearer APIKEY' \
           --data-raw '{
             "signal": "restart"
           }'
```

Comment: That sadly didn't solve it, github still tells me that there's a syntax error.

Comment: Fixing the indentation did it for me - thank you!